# Fail to load different content in modal Table

Tags: javascript, django

I have two bootstrap tables, one of them (`table_compras`) calls a modal (`table_modal`) depending on the column clicked, but i am having troubles refreshing the content rows in table, here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="modalTable" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Acumulado por Obra</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="bodyIP">
                        <table id="table_modal" data-detail-view="true" data-checkbox-header="true" data-search="true" 
                                data-search-align="left" data-detail-filter="detailFilter" data-pagination="true">
                            <thead id="thDel">
                                <tr>                                
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS Here i am getting the row and column index to populate the modal table but when I click on a different cell it continues getting the same data rows of the first cell. I have tried the commented lines of code but none of them give me the desired result :

```
var $table_compras = $('#table_compras')
            var $table = $('#table_modal')

            $(function() {
                $('#modalTable').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    $table.bootstrapTable('resetView');

                })
                $('#modalTable').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    //var table = $('#table_modal').DataTable();
                    //table.clear();
                    //$("#table_modal tr").remove();
                    //$('#table_modal').empty();
                    //$(e.target).removeData('bs.modal');
                    $('#table_modal').detach();
                    //$("#table_modal").empty();
                    //$("#table_modal thead").remove();
                    //$('#modalTable').removeData();

                })

            });

            $('#table_compras').on('click-cell.bs.table', function (field, value, row, $el) 
            {
                buildTable2($table, 2, $el.C1, value);                    
                $("#modalTable").modal();

                //alert($el.C1+"-"+$el.C2+"-"+$el.C3+"---"+value);

            });

            function buildTable2($el, cells, ano, mes) 
            {

                var columns = []
                var data = []                       

                columns.push({ field: 'C1', title: 'idObra', sortable: true})
                columns.push({ field: 'C2', title: 'Nombre', sortable: true})
                columns.push({ field: 'C3', title: 'Monto', sortable: true})
                columns.push({ field: 'C4', title: '% Participacion', sortable: true})                  


                {% for obra in cobros_por_obra %}
                    var noMes =  parseInt('{{obra.1}}');
                    noMes = noMes + 1;                        

                    if ('{{obra.0}}' == ano &&  'C' + noMes == mes)
                    {
                        //console.log('C' + noMes, mes);
                        row = {}

                        row['C1'] = '{{obra.2}}';
                        row['C2'] = '{{obra.3}}';
                        row['C3'] = '$' + Number({{obra.4}}).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
                        row['C4'] = Number({{obra.4}}).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');

                        data.push(row)
                    }
                {% endfor %}                   

                console.log(data);                 

                $el.bootstrapTable({
                columns: columns,
                data: data,
                detailView: cells > 2,
                onExpandRow: function (index, row, $detail) {
                    /* eslint no-use-before-define: ["error", { "functions": false }]*/
                    //console.log($detail)
                    expandTable($detail, cells - 1, row.C1)
                    }
                });

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it work:

Just added:

```
var $body = $('#bodyIP')
```

and change all $table for $body:

```
$('#table_compras').on('click-cell.bs.table', function (field, value, row, $el) 
            {

                buildTable2($body.html('<table data-search="true" data-search-align="left" data-detail-filter="detailFilter" data-pagination="true"></table>').find('table'), 2, $el.C1, value);


                $("#modalTable").modal();

                //alert($el.C1+"-"+$el.C2+"-"+$el.C3+"---"+value);

            });
```